# Using variables to pass arguments to a cmdlet in powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to write a little script in powershell, specifically using exchange. All it does is asks for the sender and/or recipient, and then feeds back the the tracking logs based on a date, either specified or the last 30 days.

I'm trying to use a switch to check which variables are completed, and then generates the arguments in a variable, which is then passed to the cmdlet, but this fails with "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument".

Manaully entering the command with the contents of the variable completes, but using the variable itself doesn't even outside of the switch

```
Switch ($i) { 
'1' {$x = "-Sender $sender -Start $date"}
'2' {$x = "-recipient $recipient -Start $date"}
'3' {$x = "-Sender $sender -Recipient $Recipient -Start $date"}
}

Get-MessageTrackingLog $x | Select timestamp, ServerHostName, Sender, recipients, MessageSubject, eventID, EventData | Out-GridView
```

This is the part of the script which fails. $i is an variable which counts up based on

```
if (!($sender)) {$i = $i}
else {$i = $i + 1}
if (!($recipient)) {$i = $i}
else {$i = $i + 2}
```

which might not be the most ideal solution, but works fine.

I know I can just have the switch run the whole command, and this works, but I'm trying to avoid this so that I can add to the script as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call it like this with `invoke-expression` cmdlet ( `iex` is the alias):

```
iex "Get-MessageTrackingLog $x" | Select timestamp, ServerHostName, Sender, recipients, MessageSubject, eventID, EventData | Out-GridView
```